# Call Flotr class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file to draw a graph with the following code:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="flotr2.min.js">

</script>

<body>

<div id="graph_area"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

 var container = document.getElementById('graph_area'),graph;

 var data =[[2009,9146],[2008, 9484],[2007, 10129],[2006, 10225],[2005, 10158],[2004, 9385],[2003, 9659],[2002, 9369],[2001, 8890],[1999, 8259],[1998, 9257]];

 graph = Flotr.draw(container, [ data ],null);

})();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

It is not showing up anything in the browser.

I kept `flotr2.min.js` in the same folder as this file is in.

> I am getting an error saying: "Flotr" is undefined.

Please help me.

Comment: please try inspect element, by pressing `F12` (chrome/firefox), select _network_ tab and check the script status.

Comment: I debugged in IE and that's how I got the error: 
"Flotr" is undefined

Comment: I dont know how you debug in IE but in chrome/firefox you can check if your script is retrieved or not

Comment: I debugged in firefox and script got executed. When the pointer is at Flotr.draw, it just came off. 
I added a alert statement and checked if the control goes to the next line. It did not.

Comment: then your js path is correct. perhaps you can try to download other version of flotr

Comment: Thanks, the error is somehow gone. But it is still showing an empty page while the expected result was some chart.

Answer (score 0):

#### If error saying: "Flotr" is undefined... means your js path is not proper.

Comment: lotr2.min.js in the same folder as the html file. Should I change it to something else?

Answer (score 0):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967612/call-flotr-class-in-javascript/20968676#comment31499728_20967612) you're missing to add width and height for the `graph-area` , hence it is not showing in your browser.

Add this and see

```
#graph_area {
    width: 340px;
    height: 220px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFBj5/825/)

Comment: I added the style, but no use. And also, I added xaxis, yaxis min & max as well. Nothing is coming up.

Comment: @user3069288 have you checked my fiddle? it is working right?